# How to use CA certificate to connect to database in java

Tags: java, ssl, jdbc, ca

Currently I'm connecting to Database that doesn't need a CA certificate as follows:

```
input = new FileInputStream("path/to/properties/file");
prop.load(input);

Class.forName(prop.getProperty("JDBC_DRIVER"));
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(prop.getProperty("DB_URL"), prop.getProperty("USER"), prop.getProperty("PASS"));
```

Now the requirements have changed and i have to connect to the database using CA certificate which i have. 
Now I'm trying the following:

```
String url = prop.getProperty("DB_URL")+"?verifyServerCertificate=false"+"&useSSL=true"+"&requireSSL=true";
Class.forName(prop.getProperty("JDBC_DRIVER"));
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, prop.getProperty("USER"), prop.getProperty("PASS"));
```

Could you tell me how I can provide the path to the CA certificate and successfully connect to the database.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to connect to the database using SSL(CA certificate):

```
input = new FileInputStream("path/to/properties/file");
    prop.load(input);

    Class.forName(prop.getProperty("JDBC_DRIVER"));
    System.getProperties().setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",
            "/path_to_certificate");
    String url = prop.getProperty("DB_URL")
            + "?verifyServerCertificate=false" + "&useSSL=true"
            + "&requireSSL=true"; 
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url, prop.getProperty("USER"),
            prop.getProperty("PASS"));
```

This one worked for me.

Comment: It should be `/path_to_truststore`, and the ``getProperties()` part is redundant.

Comment: as well `verifyServerCertificate=false` makes you vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attack

Comment: Will make the suggested changes. Thanks.